# Anchor Name Tags not working on Apple

Tags: wordpress, anchor

We have a one page (well two if you count the Spanish version) wordpress site using the Right Way them that uses anchor name tags to navigate down and up the page. The client recently said that the menu wasn't working on a Mac. She thinks the person is using chrome.

Here an example link: http://masstrategic.com/home/#how-we-do-it

And here is the code:

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">
Fortunately, WE DO.
<br>
<a id="how-we-do-it" class="sc_anchor" data-description="How We Do It" data-icon="inherit" data-url="" data-separator="no" name="how-we-do-it" title="How We Do It"></a>
<br>
MAS Strategic Communications specializes in Spanish media and public relations, public affairs, content development, grassroots activity, translation services, political affairs, and media coaching.
</p>
```

There are some extra classes and stuff the the theme throws in but it has an ID and a NAME both with the same tag inside that matches the URL.

I guess none of the links work but they were talking about the Blog link specifically.

Any ideas as to why this doesn't work?

Thanks,
Matt

Update: I just double checked and the problem is happening on Safari as well.

Comment: Is there a reason as to why the anchor tag is missing a href attribute? I'm not sure this will solve the problem but sometimes anchor tags don't want to work with out a href attribute.

Comment: The href should only be needed in a link this is just an anchor for the link. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp

Answer (score 1):

please put http:// before your URL that will work fine in apple mail and other app & browser too

```
<a href="http://UR_URL">url</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general - I've only heard of this problem in iOS safari - but one thing to try is change your URL and append `www` to it.

**from this:**
http://masstrategic.com/home/#how-we-do-it

**to this:**
http://www.masstrategic.com/home/#how-we-do-it

Comment: I am having the client test this now. The problem is that before the link would scroll down on the page (the English version still does this) but with www it now reloads the page everytime and then jumps rather than scrolls. See the spanish version: http://masstrategic.com/bienvenidos/. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't change the English version. Just the Spanish version's menu.